# Get last visible div's attribute

Tags: jquery, html

This is kind of hard to explain. Here's an example of my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div row="1">
    </div>
    <div row="2">
    </div>
    <div row="3">
    </div>
    <div row="4">
    </div>
    <div row="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to basically find the last `<div>` in the `container` `<div>` and get the `row` attribute from it. This 99% of the time ends up being the biggest number, but not guaranteed to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`last-child-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) to fetch the last row, then the [`attr()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method to get the value of the attribute.

```
var row = $('#container > div:last-child').attr('row');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TZyPT/

You may want to consider the HTML5 `data-` attribute for custom attributes. jQuery supports it in older browsers with the [`data()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
<div id="container">
    <div data-row="1">
    </div>
    <div data-row="2">
    </div>
    <div data-row="3">
    </div>
    <div data-row="4">
    </div>
    <div data-row="5">
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
var row = $('#container > div:last-child').data('row');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/TZyPT/1/

Comment: Will this infinite loop if there's no inner divs?

Comment: @slandau: No. jQuery methods just fail quietly when there are no matching elements.

Comment: Hmm, from the jQuery documentation: "While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more than one: one for each parent." Maybe changing it to :last might have a slight increase in performance? Or not, since there's only one parent. Does anyone know? I'm curious now.

Comment: @with a dot.: I think that either way, the selector engine will have to start by finding all `div` elements, then reducing to those with the parent `#container` and finally filtering down to the last one. The advantage of using `:last-child` over `:last` is that `:last` is not a valid CSS selector while `:last-child` is, so `querySelectorAll` will be used in browsers that support it, which will give extremely fast results compared to using a javascript based selector engine.

Comment: ...that was what I meant in the comment under your answer when I wrote *"using a fully valid selector"*.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has a lovely method for that:

```
$('div#container > div').last().attr('row')
```